# Building C-library - undefined reference - what is wrong?

Tags: c, android-ndk, openal

I'm trying to build a c-library (OpenAL-MOB). I'm using Android NDK-build.
I'm getting the following errors, which I don't understand. Can someone help me?

Errors:

```
In function MixDirect_Hrtf_SUF
FIX:C:/Development/OpenAL-MOB-1.0.0/OpenAL-MOB-1.0.0/build_android//jni/../../Al
c/mixer_inc.c:116: error: undefined reference to 'ApplyCoeffsStep'

In function MixDirect_Hrtf_SUF
FIX:C:/Development/OpenAL-MOB-1.0.0/OpenAL-MOB-1.0.0/build_android//jni/../../Al
c/mixer_inc.c:136: error: undefined reference to 'ApplyCoeffs'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [C:/Development/OpenAL-MOB-1.0.0/OpenAL-MOB-1.0.0/build_android//o
bj/local/armeabi/libopenal.so] Error 1
```

Mixer_inc.c:

```
__inline void ApplyCoeffsStep(ALuint Offset, ALfloat (*RESTRICT Values)[2],
                                 const ALuint irSize,
                                 ALfloat (*RESTRICT Coeffs)[2],
                                 const ALfloat (*RESTRICT CoeffStep)[2],
                                 ALfloat left, ALfloat right);

__inline void ApplyCoeffs(ALuint Offset, ALfloat (*RESTRICT Values)[2],
                             const ALuint irSize,
                             ALfloat (*RESTRICT Coeffs)[2],
                             ALfloat left, ALfloat right);

void MixDirect_Hrtf(const DirectParams *params, const ALfloat *RESTRICT data, ALuint srcchan,
ALuint OutPos, ALuint SamplesToDo, ALuint BufferSize)
{
    ...

    ApplyCoeffsStep(Offset, Values, IrSize, Coeffs, CoeffStep, left, right);

    ...

    ApplyCoeffs(Offset, Values, IrSize, Coeffs, left, right);

    ...
}
```

Source code: [OpenAL-MOB source code](https://github.com/Jawbone/OpenAL-MOB/tree/master/Alc)

Comment: With such very specific questions about a specific software on a specific platform, you'd probably are better off when contacting the developpers directly through their own channels. Would be pure luck to find somebody on SO from that community.

Comment: Jens, I hoped that it was a general C-error. I'm not very experienced with C. But you may be right, if it's not a general error, I'll remove the question and ask one of the autors.